# Blender version(s) useable on Linux PCs with CPUs without SSE2?

Tags: versions

Several computer science students in developing countries, who only have access to old PCs with non-SSE2 CPUs (mostly AthlonXP processors with SSE1), would like to know the version number of the last Blender before this great application began to be compiled to take advantage of SSE2. The machines use the Ubuntu based Linux Mint version of the Linux operating system.

If anybody could advise the best and most stable edition that can run on such machine I would be sincerely grateful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Here is a list of previous releases.  You may need to use some trial and error with this to find out what works.  http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: While there are 32bit versions available to download, you should be able to use the newest version of blender but maybe you need to compile it yourself. If you have one faster machine and want to use it to compile for the other machines you can specify `-march=athlon-xp` in the CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to be sure the compiled app will run on the older cpu's. I have seen issues compiling using gcc4.2 so you may want to install gcc4.6 or clang to compile with. [See this wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender)